# Regexp replace without interaction

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace

Is it possible to replace regex like query-replace-regex without asking for each matching ?

Comment: There is always `replace-regexp` (note the lack of the `query-` prefix). Not posting this as an answer since I am not quite sure where you want to go with the second question. Also, note that even with `query-replace-regexp`, you can try it out on a match or two, just to see you got it right, then hit `!` and it will do the rest without asking. The keypress `,` is very useful in this mode: It replaces, but does not move on, so you can see what happened.

Comment: Thanks, replace-regexp is the answer to the first, I understand why it's called query now. For the second quetsion I would like to type something like `s/regexp/replace/options`, using sed would be a solution.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple unrelated questions in the same post. Edit the sed/vim bit out of this, and ask it in a separate question. Harald Hanche-Olsen can then convert that comment to a proper answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `replace-regexp` (note the absence of the `query-` prefix).

But also, note the `!` keybinding when running `query-replace-regexp`. It will replace all occurences beyond point without further questions.